# Bootstrap in Appium

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium

What does mean by bootstrap in Appium and why it used for?

> The scripts will then communicate with `bootstrap.jar` which is
>   running in device

Answer (score 1):

From the source ***[Appium-Android-Bootstrap](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-bootstrap)*** :

> JavaScript interface, and Java code, for interacting with Android UI
>   Automator. The system allows ad hoc commands to be sent to the device,
>   which are executed using Android's UIAutomator testing framework

So, the thought behind the theory is all the interactions or actions you are able to perform on the *Appium UI* or *using the client* are built over the bootstrap interface which is thereon build over the Android's UIAutomator used by the `appium-android-bootstrap code`.